# Getting total points for all of User's Submissions Django

Tags: python, django

I have two simple models:

```
class Task(TimeStampedModel):
    ...
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    points = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Submission(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='submissions')
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name='task_submissions')
    ...
```

I'm struggling to figure out, what I think should be a simple query, with Django's ORM.

Let's say I have a total of 6 `Submissions` by 3 unique `Users`:

```
[<Submission: John Doe>, <Submission: Ricky Bobby, <Submission: Ricky Bobby>, <Submission: John Doe>, <Submission: Jane Smith>, <Submission: Jane Smith>]
```

Now, what I really want is to query all `Submissions` and total up the `Task` points for each User, but only want **one** of each unique `User` and add a (what I think should be an annotated) property called `total` to each `User`.

So what I'd get back really is:

```
[<Submission: John Doe>, <Submission: Ricky Bobby, <Submission: Jane Smith>]
```

And each `Submission` would now have an extra property called `total` that is the sum of all that user's `Submission` `Task` points.  So if the `User` has 2 submissions with task points of 5 and 5 the total would be 10.

I am trying all kinds of things but just not "getting" how to construct the query and spinning my wheels so I thought I'd reach out to the community.

> Note: I don't simply want each 'user' and their 'total' as a response, I want the entire user object along with the new property of 'total' so I have all the user's data and the total points they have for all their submissions.

**UPDATE:**
I should note I have tried:

```
Submission.objects.all().annotate(total=Sum('task__points'))
```

But this still gives me the same 6 results, when I want 3 results (one for each unique User) along with their total points (for all that User's submissions).

**SOLUTION:**
Thanks to Christian for pointing me in the right direction, here is my final query:

```
leaders = User.objects.filter(~Q(submissions=None)) \
        .filter(submissions__status='approved') \
        .annotate(total=Sum('submissions__task__points')) \
        .order_by('-total')
```

> Note: The above query gets all Users who have Submissions (as not all users have Submissions) that are approved and totals up the points for each task submitted and orders them highest to lowest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want Django's [`annotate` feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregations-and-other-queryset-clauses). Try something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
User.objects.all().annotate(total=Sum('submission__task__points'))
```

Comment: That is what I first tried, but it still produces 6 results.  Since there are 6 submissions, by only 3 unique users I am looking for a response with the 3 unique users and their total points as well.

Comment: Ah! So close!  That was it.  I was going from the Submissions model when I really should have been going in reverse and getting the User's submissions and totaling the submissions task points.  Thanks so much Christian!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. :)